# C++ Random number generator, isnt random but always returns the same number

Tags: c++, random

Hi im looking for RandNum to generate a number between 2-10, and then that number being taken away from 15.

Right now, every time the program is executed, the number taken away from 15, (PerseusHealth) is 7. How do i fix this, and make it random?

```
void desertpath()
{
int scorpianchoice; //the option the player chooses.
int Maxhit = 10; //Max hit the scorpian can do
int Minhit = 2; //Min hit the scorpian can do

int randNum = rand()%(Maxhit + Minhit) + Minhit; 
int healthremaining = PerseusHealth - randNum; //health left in option1.


if(scorpianchoice == 1)
{
    cout << "You run under the Scorpians Legs in hopes to escape " << endl;
    cout << "You are hit by the scorpians Sting for " << randNum << " hp!";
    cout << "You have " << healthremaining << "/15 HP Left!" << endl;
    cout << "You escape the Scorpian but not without taking some damage" << endl;
}
```

Comment: [`srand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) to solve the immediate problem. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random for future reading.

Comment: Call `srand` (only once) as the program starts up, typically passing it the current time, like `srand(time(NULL))`. Better still, switch to using `std::mt19936` and `std::random_device` to do the seeding.

Comment: In your snippet you are using uninitialized variable `scorpianchoice`.

Comment: ...and there's no "a" in scorpion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use srand to initialize.

```
srand((unsigned)time(0));
```

Also, I think you have not put the brackets correctly:

```
int randNum = (rand()%(Maxhit - Minhit)) + Minhit;
```

Comment: and make it Maxhit-Minhit

Comment: @hennessyd On top of @ebad86 answer there are two issues more related to quality of the sampling. One is due to biased low bits of the rand(). Another is bias due to using `%`.

Answer (score 0):

Clarification on top of @ebad86 answer

1. rand() is known for bad quality, especially when low bits are used. Most likely, for example, output is always generated with low bit set to 1. Simple solution might be to use bits from the middle of the sequence by shifting bits (say, by 8)
2. If max generated output of rand() is not divisible by (Maxhit-Minhit), you'll get (slightly) biased result. It might be ok for your purposes, but you'd better know it